# Lua program not working

Tags: lua

I decided to try and recreate a sorting algorithm in Lua just for fun. It works for some values, but in larger values that have repeating numbers, it doesn't work properly. I was wondering why this is happening.

Here's the code (I added comments to make it easier to see):

```
numbers = "9876554321" -- Number to sort, I will refer to this as the "string to sort"
length = tonumber(string.len(numbers)) -- The length of the string to sort
changes = 1 -- The next few lines are just variables
totalchanges = 0
iterations = 0
newNumbers = numbers
print("")
while changes ~= 0 do -- This repeats until the number of changes equals zero
  iterations = iterations + 1 -- This variable doesn't do anything for the code, it's only used at the end
  changes = 0
  print(newNumbers)
  x = 1 -- More variables
  y = 0
  z = 0
  w = false
  while x < length do -- While the x variable is less than the length of the string to sort, repeat this code
    y = tonumber(string.sub(newNumbers, x, x)) -- The 'x'th place in the string
    z = tonumber(string.sub(newNumbers, x + 1, x + 1)) -- The 'x + 1'th place in the string
    w = y > z -- If the 'x'th place is larger than the 'x + 1'th place, this value is set to true
    print(y) -- Print statements
    print(z)
    print(w)
    if w == true then -- Checks if y > z is true
      newNumbers = string.gsub(newNumbers, tostring(z), tostring(y), 1)  -- The next two lines swap around the numbers if y > z
      newNumbers = string.gsub(newNumbers, tostring(y), tostring(z), 1)
      changes = changes + 1 -- Increases the number of changes
    end
    print("")
    x = x + 1 -- Increases the x value, this lets the code know where to check in the string
  end
  totalchanges = totalchanges + changes -- This variable is like the iterations variable, it's only used for the last print statements
end
print("") -- These last print statements are just showing information about the sort
print("Sorting complete!")
print("Original string: " .. tostring(numbers))
print("Sorted string: " .. tostring(newNumbers))
print("Total changes made: " .. tostring(totalchanges))
print("Total iterations used: " .. tostring(iterations))
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What specifically is the issue that is being produced by your code. Please describe that.

Comment: do I expect too much if I think you should at least bother to add a few comments to code you want help on?

Comment: @RyanSchaefer The problem is that some numbers, like the one I set for the code, "9876554321", do not get sorted all the way. They get stuck in some number (In this case, "1234567895") and the code never continues because the program still thinks that there is a change going on.

Comment: @Piglet I'm sorry about not adding comments to the code. I edited some comments in, hopefully it makes it easier to see.

Comment: The problem with this implementation of bubble-sort is in "The next two lines swap around the numbers".  Actually, those two lines do not swap numbers at specified positions.  They swap first (from the left) copies of these numbers, not the numbers you need.

Comment: You might consider loading your string one character at a time into an array.  Then, write your bubble sort to sort the array.  That'd allow you to focus on the bubble sort algorithm, instead of fighting with lua to move characters around in a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
newNumbers = string.gsub(newNumbers, tostring(z), tostring(y), 1)      
newNumbers = string.gsub(newNumbers, tostring(y), tostring(z), 1)
```

These two lines are just wrong on so many levels.

Let's start with only one of them: Assuming `z == 5`, and in your example code there's 2 `5`s, *every* `5` in the sequence would get turned into `y`, not only the one you are trying to swap.

Next is the even more obvious problem that you first turn all `z`s into `y`s, and then all `y`s into `z`s. The problem here is that you also turn into `z`s the `y`s that you just turned into `y`s, so basically

```
aaaayzaa -> aaaayyaa -> aaaazzaa
```

and **not**

```
aaaayzaa -> aaaazyaa
```

---

Even if that wasn't the case though, don't use strings for that kind of stuff. Strings in Lua are a bit different<sup>1</sup> than usual. You'd be much better off turning the string into a sequence, doing stuff with it, and finally concatenating it back into a string.

Also keep in mind that you can directly compare two characters, and Lua will compare them lexicographically, so no need to `tostring()` everything. `"2" < "9"` works just as `2 < 9` would.

---

<sup>1</sup> [*Lua Performance Tips* by Roberto Ierusalimschy, page 22 "About Strings"](https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf)